# The xml for analysis request timed ,when trying to connect ssas cube from Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, ssas-2008, xmla, data-connections

There are workbook connections in excel sheet, which connects to an analysis service cube. All connections connects to same cube on same server.
only One of the connection keep giving the following error message!!!

```
Data could not be retrieved from the external data source. Error message returned by external data source:

xml for analysis parser; The xml for analysis request timed out before it was completed
```